# uiautomator dump does not work on lxc-attach

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, lxc

I am running android as a container inside the Linux. I want to run an adb command on android container.

I ran this command from Linux console

`lxc-attach -n mycontainer -- /system/bin/uiautomator dump /sdcard/dump.xml`

Above command does not showing any output on screen.  Neither it creates /sdcard/dump.xml file and dump.

But i am seeing this command works
`lxc-attach -n mycontainer -- /system/bin/screencap /sdcard/image.png`

Comment: How do you run Android in a container? 
Does that command work when you run it interactively in the container?

Comment: yes. it works when i run it interactively. but my issue is i cant run interactively in my test framework. so need to get the output with single command.

Comment: If you can share some info on how to run Android in a container, it would be great. I am interested in this. If a command runs OK interactively but not non-interactively, then it is likely the command requires `stdin` or `stderr` and cannot find it. You can try to redirect the input to null.